# ASP.NET Change session value when change page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Hello community of stack overflow, this is my first question and I will try be clear.
Im developing a projet that is a school work in ASP.NET C#.

Im trying to change the value of a SESSION when the user change the WebForm by any button or by the URl bar. I already tried that with javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

        function confirmExit() {
            '<%Session["teste"] = "changed"; %>';
        }

 </script>
```

For testing In the WebForm1 I give to the SESSION an value at the PageLoad event:

```
Session["teste"] = "teste";
```

Then when I go to WebForm2 by the URl bar and I print the value of the SESSION to a label the result is "changed", the value that I want, but if I go to the WebForm2 by an ASP button the value of the SESSION still be "teste". Somebody know how I can solve my issue? Thanks.

Comment: where does that javascript reside..? are you using a MasterPage..? 
also are you familiar with the OnSessionStart Method in the Global.asax page.. I would recommend using `HttpContext.Current.Session["teste"]` vs `Session["teste"]` in the Page_Load of the MasterPage you would need to check `If(IsPost_Back){ }` then set your value.. vs trying to add `Session["teste"]` on every Pages Load event..

Comment: Im not using MasterPages, That javascript code is in the WebForm1.

Comment: You can not set a session variable using javascript unless you make an ajax call to a page and pass the value through (but then you would still need some server side code to set it)

Comment: is this a single page only in your project..?

Comment: @MethodMan No, I have some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google information on the ASP.NET page lifecycle. There's a `Page_OnUnload` event that fires when the user navigates away from the page.

I think there's a way to hook into this in all the pages in the app, in Global.asax or the master pages, perhaps? (You'd just need to do this in all the masterpages if you have more than one)

Comment: Thanks for the help, works 100%, changing by URL bar or ASP button. Code:  `<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["teste"] = "changed";
}
</script>`

Comment: You ought to print this out and refer to it - it's a great resource, I was always looking at something like this when I started: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_Li2NlT9UdAY/TB8AmvnH2II/AAAAAAAAAEI/ldghqAYPu5Y/s1600/aspnet_page-control-life-cycle.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This may help you. check the link first, you have to read about session in asp.net
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.140).aspx